# Meteor: Block access to application if user's email is not verified

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to restrict accessibility to the app and redirect the user to a path that renders a template stating "please check your email and verify your email."

The user receives a verification link upon account creation, when they click it, emails.verified is then set to `true` - great.

Between the time of account creation and verifying their email, I would like to restrict access to the application. I dont want a user to create profile on my app and post online as they maybe a 'malicious' user.

**SOLUTION ONE ?**: upon account creation, can I log the user out immediately and direct them to a path with the template message "please check your email and verify your email."

Then, on `Accounts.onLogin`, check if a users email is verified or not.

server.js

```
 if ( user.user.emails.verified === false ) {
     //render please verify email template
      }
      else  {
       //continue as usual
       }



Accounts.config({
 sendVerificationEmail: true,
 forbidClientAccountCreation: false,
 loginExpirationInDays: null
});
```

Is there a simpler and more logical method that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Iron Router you can add a before hook:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(){
  if (Meteor.loggingIn()){
    this.render('loading');
  } else if (Meteor.user() && !Meteor.user().emails[0].verified){
    this.render('verification');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a client-side solution and is therefore circumventable.  If you're looking for a secure solution you'll have to block the log-in on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Iron Router you can add logic to a route so that when you login you are redirected based on whether or not you have confirmed. This would also solve the problem of "logging out immediately" after a user registered. That doesn't sound like the best user experience. Routing with a bit of logic could solve that issue.

Comment: Thanks Tim, and it seems Jeremy S has provided what I may be looking for.

Comment: This is a client-side solution and is therefore circumventable.  If you're looking for a secure solution you'll have to block the log-in on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You might have solved the problem, but I think it's worth it to share few links that offer better approaches in solving this. They're router-agnostic and take advantage of an already existing method in Accounts package.

[#1] On blocking the data published by server by checking against the user's email's verification status to ensure there's no data leakage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15384012/3112047

[#2] On using [Accounts.validateLoginAttempt](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt) to block login attempts if the Boolean parameter taken is set to *false*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24940581/3112047