# Meteor : Stop login if email is unverified

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

In my meteor.js app I only want verified users signing in. They must click the link in their email first. 
*I don't see any official mention of this in the documentation. Any ideas?*

**client javascript**

```
Template.login.events({

  'submit #login-form' : function(e,t){
    e.preventDefault();

    var email    = t.find('#email').value;
    var password = t.find('#password').value;

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(error){
      if (error){
        console.log(error);
      }
      else{
        console.log("success");
      }
    });

    return false; 

    }
});
```

There are some stackoverflow posts but these only cover blocking  unverified users from viewing certain pages:

[Meteor: Block access to application if user's email is not verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081524/meteor-block-access-to-application-if-users-email-is-not-verified)

Comment: Please do not edit an answer in your question. Instead, create a new answer and accept it if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***/lib/methods.js***

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

      checkEmailVerification: function(email) {
        found_user = Meteor.users.findOne({ 'emails.address' : email })
        if(found_user){
            if(found_user.emails[0].verified == true){
                return "verified";
            }else{
                return "unverified";
            }
        }else{
            return "notfound";
        }
      }
    });
});
```

**/client/login.js**

```
Template.login.events({

  'submit #login' : function(event, t){
    event.preventDefault();

    var email    = t.find('#email').value;
    var password = t.find('#password').value;

    Meteor.call('checkEmailVerification', email, function(error,data){
      if (data == "verified"){
          Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err){
            if (err){
              FlashMessages.sendError("Either email or password is incorrect");
            }
            else{
              FlashMessages.sendSuccess("Logged in");
             }
          });
      }else if(data == "unverified"){
          FlashMessages.sendError("Check your email for a verification link");
      }else{
          FlashMessages.sendError("Either email or password is incorrect");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is check for the verified token inside the Accounts db.

Something of this sort:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        'get_users_by_email': function(email) {
            return Users.findOne({ emails.address: email }).fetch()[0].verified;
        }
    });
}
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    a = Meteor.call('get_users_by_email', 'email-entered-by-user');
}
```

Then, you can check whether a is true or false.

When a is false, you could login the user, and when it is true, you can prevent the login by showing an error or whateever you want to tell people who have verified email adresses.

Comment: This syntax is wrong but I will use this concept and try and figure it out. The error is "Accounts.find is not a function". I'll shuffle my way through it and comment back here so we can update your answer and help the community. Thanks!! @Abhi

Comment: Yeah I can't seem to find the command to get users based on email (clientside at least) @Abhi

Comment: See the edit answer and check if that works for you.

Comment: thanks that lead me in the right direction. I got it. If you want to see it you can check out my update !! thanks again @abhi abhi