# Meteor: verification upon registration before login

Tags: meteor

I would like to have my app send out a verification email when a user has registered. Current behaviour is that he is immediately (and automatically) logged in after registration. Whenever a user hits the registration button, I perform validation of the fields and call the 'Accounts.createUser' function. This works good. Note: am using a custom user authentication, not accounts-ui or useraccounts.

I would however prefer him to validate his email and only when this is successful, his account should be activated.

To achieve this I configured:

```
Accounts.config({
    sendVerificationEmail: true
});
```

The idea would be that an email is sent to the user in the Accounts.createUser function. My app is effectively sending out a verification email in the form 'http://localhost:3000/verify-email/' but the registered user is again automatically logged in.

- Any ideas?
- I have a route configured for the verification. Should I
  set the "verified" parameter (in mongo) to true via code in the js file of the template?

Comment: releated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383273/force-email-validation-before-login-meteor?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I saw that one as well but I don't like the proposed solution.  I understand the pubsub validations this person is proposing, but in no case a customer that has not been verified should get access to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `enforceEmailVerification: true` check the docs https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using useraccounts as such. But I found this solution to be working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383273/force-email-validation-before-login-meteor?rq=1

Comment: because you use Accounts.config  i assumed you use the core.

Comment: Thanks. Am developing the user authentication myself as I want to have full flexibility in future. Although I like useraccounts as well but lacks some flexibility sometimes