# Meteor Accounts-ui to wait for email verification before user access

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

A Meteor web app on the local machine uses `Accounts-password` and `Accounts-ui`.
The user enters email and password in order to create a new account.

It needs to be configured so that the user gets a userId (thus become a currentUser) only after verifying the creation of the accounts via email.

The app has an smtp variable set up. It send the verification email fine. but it failed to prevent the user to 'login' before the verification. How can it be made so that it only gives a valid userId after the verification? Thanks

```js
//server
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  Accounts.config({
    sendVerificationEmail: true
  });
  return user;
});
```

Comment: First, you don't need to call `Accounts.config()` every time a user is created. Control of the logins can be done via [`Accounts.validateLoginAttempt`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-validateLoginAttempt).

Comment: @MasterAM is that instead of onCreateUser?

Comment: These are 2 different APIs. You should read the docs to know what you can do. Better than guessing. You said you want to prevent login, so this ius the API call you need to target.

Comment: @MasterAM There are not docs with examples and tutorials on how much juice can be squeezed out of it. Any idea how to use it in my use case?

Comment: A verification email is sent with an verification token embedded. The token is used to identify and validate the target a user, aka a user who has identification to be validated. Based on the design principles of the `accounts` packages in Meteor, I would advise you to not prevent user creation but restrict users' privileges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force email validation before login meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383273/force-email-validation-before-login-meteor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I define a global helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('isVerified',function(){ // return a true or false depending on whether the referenced user's email has been verified
  if ( Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().emails ) return Meteor.user().emails[0].verified; // look at the current user
  else return false;
});
```

And then in any template (typically my master template) I can do:

```
{{#if isVerified}}
  content that only verified users should see
{{else}}
  Please check your email for your verification link!
{{/if}}
```

Comment: One problem with this code is that if no records exists for the user, it will run the `{{else}}` block.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it is fairly easy to bypass. Whether that is sufficient or not depends on how critical the email verification is (if this is only a "nudge" to remind the user to verify the email, that is reasonable).

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite as simple as all that. Meteor needs a user to have an ID in order to send them an email. What you want to do is probably not actually prevent a login, but prevent the  In order to do what you want, you'll have to prevent them from seeing anything when they *are* logged in. Something like this in your top-level template:

```js
{{#if userVerified}}
  // Body of your app here
  {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
{{else}}
  You are not yet verified
{{/if}}
```

And this in the corresponding `.js` file:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  userVerified () {
    const user = Meteor.user();
    return user.emails[0].verified;
  }
});
```

Comment: user.emails.verified = false, yet `{{#if currentUser}}` is returning true. How come?

Comment: D'oh! It's returning true because they're logged in. I updated the snippet to instead return true only if they are verified as well.

Answer (score 1):

As @Season has pointed out, the verification requires that a userId be created in order to link it to the verification email.

What you could do is prevent a user from logging in if they haven't verified their email. See this answer to another question which accomplishes that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24940581/3512709