# Disable login after resetting password in Meteor accounts-password

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, react-router, meteor-accounts

How to disable login after resetting password in Meteor accounts-password package?

After sending reset link to guest's email, I have this code to reset the password,

```
Accounts.resetPassword(this.props.params.token, this.refs.password.value.trim(),(err) => {
            if(err){
                Bert.alert( err, 'danger', 'growl-top-right');
            } else {
                Bert.alert( "Password is successfully changed.", 'success', 'growl-top-right');
            }
            this.setState({resetPassword:false});
            this.refs.password.value = "";
        });
```

After few seconds, it will auto login the user to dashboard page. The problem here is, I have different type of users, guest (which cannot login), admin (who has access to manage users) and staff ( the verified user of the app).
If guest reset their password, they automatically logged in which is wrong.

How can I disable autologin?

By the way, I am using Meteor + React JS with React-router.

Here is my Validate Login Attempt code,

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt((data)=>{
    if(data.error)
        return data.error;
    if(!data.user.emails[0].verified)
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Verify email account first');
    if((data.user.profile && data.user.profile.retired) || (data.user.roles.company.includes("guest")))
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Account must be accepted by an admin');
    else
        return true;
});
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it, but it sounds like it's your app is not properly planned out. Why can't you make all users able to log in, but limit the features based on their authorization levels? Instead of having their permissions set based on whether they have a verified address or not.

Comment: Guests can register using company account. So I allowed registering on public page. but they need to confirmed that the registered user is a staff before they can login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`AccountsServer#validateLoginAttempt(func)`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-validateLoginAttempt) method to test whether the `user` of the object passed into the callback is a guest, and if so, return a falsy value.

This is done on the server-side.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24940581/3966682) provides an example implementation based on whether the user has a verified email.

Comment: I added validateLoginAttempt code. But seems not working.